How to test the Realm db Migration script code in the React native app?
I'm not able to test the realmdb migration script it is for the stored data in realmdb and when i'm gonna update the tables in realmdb the previous versions of my app will not work it'll give migration script error.

Made the Apk with old version.
Now, added the new tables code.
Tried making the apk with new version.
It fails now.


To ensure we understand the question; Realm has no tables. It's an object based technology backed by NoSQL (which has no tables). You may be possibly referring to adding an Object Model?  What is an Apk - do you mean the App? What new tables code did you add? Please take a moment and review How to ask a question and very important How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
